# Why do Killua's and Gon's skin tones change in episode 45 and 46 Huncyclopedia?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

At the end of the 2011 *Hunter × Hunter* (episodes 27 through 58), there is a little short "Huncyclopedia", which is Gon and Killua talking about some character or element in the series.

From episodes 37 through 44, the two have a "Whale Island" theme, which shows them in shorts and out in the wild rather than in a classroom. However, in the two episodes following this, their skin tone is significantly darker. Oddly enough, they are still in their original tones for the intro, as well as [when they make animal faces at the end of episode 46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ51p.jpg).

[image: Episode 45 Huncyclopedia]

Is this supposed to be a tan, or is there some other reason for this change?

Comment: They probably got tan from being outside for so long. The ones in the intro a probably static cardboard stand-ins. Also Whale Island is probably Gon's backyard. Note sure about why they changed back to their original colors to do the cat nd dog faces. Maybe since it's all non-canon they were just like: *poof* and we're back.

Comment: What @Krazer said is pretty much the answer. Such "interesting" logic is often seen in omake sections, which are meant to be lighthearted anyway.

Comment: As you guessed this really is only supposed to be a tan. Quite a strong one, but still just a tan.

Answer (score 2):

The last one or two Hunterpedias before their skin changed were done outside, so they got sunburned. There is no official answer, but it was speculated by the community as an animation error.